# Getting file size in bytes with bash (Ubuntu)

Tags: bash

## Hi, i'm looking for a way  to output a filesize in bytes. Whatever i try i will get either 96 or 96k instead of 96000.

```
if [[ -d $1 ]]; then    
        largestN=$(find $1 -depth -type f | tr '\n' '\0' | du -s --files0-from=- | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')
        largestS=$(find $1 -depth -type f | tr '\n' '\0' | du -h --files0-from=- | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')
            echo "The largest file is $largestN which is $largestS bytes."  
else    
    echo "$1 is not a directory..."
fi
```

This prints "The largest file [file] is 96k bytes"

Comment: Do you have the `stat` command?

Answer (score 0):

there is `-b` option for this

```
$ du -b ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to find the largest file in a given directory. It's more efficient (and shorter) to let `find` do the heavy lifting for you:

```
find $1 -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -n | tail -n1
```

Here, `%s` expands to the size in bytes of the file, and `%p` expands to the name of the file.

Comment: Note printf is only avialable on GNU find.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what i needed. I'm completly new to scrips, so this was alot of help!

Comment: I would like the total size of $1 (on a new line), also in bytes. Can you give me that too?

Comment: @123 Thanks for pointing that out. I had a feeling this might be nonstandard, but neglected to check.

Comment: @TorsteinTrulsrud Try `du -s $1 | cut -f1`.